# Save a javascript function in system.js - MongoDB with Java

Tags: javascript, java, mongodb

I have to insert a javascript function in the collection `system.js` using Java driver(**<3.0.0 version**).
 
`system.js`is a special collection of MongoDB to store javascript functions for reuse. 
I need to store this function to use it with map/reduce command.

From MongoDB shell I use:

```
db.system.js.save(
   {
     _id: "echoFunction",
     value : function(x) { return x; }
   }
)
```

Using Java driver I tried to insert the function value in the form of a string:

```
try{
    MongoClient mongoclient = new MongoClient(HOST,PORT);
    DB db = mongoclient.getDB("test");
    System.out.println("Succesfully connected to MongoDB");
    DBCollection jsColl = db.getCollection("system.js");
    DBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("_id","echoFunction").append("value","function(x) {return x}");
    jsColl.insert(doc);
}
```

The `DBObject doc` is correctly added to the `system.js` collection but my function is seen from MongoDB as a String and not as a javascript function, so I am not able to use it with map/reduce command.

Comment: @DistribuzioneGuassiana how can we query this , eval is deprecated now .? Did you tried querying as well ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a Object as org.bson.types.Code into value like

```
Code functionCode = new Code ("function(x) {return x}") ; 
DBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("_id","echoFunction").append("value",functionCode);
```

Comment: how can we call this "echoFunction" with java only ?